# Webpage in webview not working as expected

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm building an app that renders a webview which allows for users to book tours to UK attraction sites through 365tickets.co.uk. When I navigate to the booking page(which lists a number of services I can book the tour through) and click the Book option, It only opens the last entry's info tab. Any ideas on what the problem could be? Here's an image of the webview open:[Webview open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psgAK.png)

Heres the activity where the webview is initiated:

```
public class TourBookingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
String museumName;

/**
 * Activity on create activity.
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour_booking);
    museumName = getIntent().getStringExtra("museum_name").toLowerCase();
    String museumNameFinal = museumName.replace(' ', '-');

    webView = findViewById(R.id.book_tour_web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.365tickets.co.uk/" +
            museumNameFinal.toLowerCase() + "?q=" +
            museumNameFinal.toLowerCase());

}

/**
 * Handle back clicked while in webview.
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I needed to add Javascript support for the webview. Added `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` and it works fine now.